# Efficient approaches for parsing objects from consecutive fixed size buffers that don't align with object size

Tags: c++, vector, arrays

I am trying to achieve something in C++, where I have an API that reads out objects from a byte array, while the array I pass in is constrained to a fixed size. After it parses out a complete object, the API knows the pointer location where it finishes reading (the beginning of next object to be read from but not complete in the current byte array).

Then I simply need to attach the remaining byte array with the next same fixed size array, and start reading a new object out at the pointer location as if it's the beginning of the new array.

I am new to C++ and I have the following approach working, but looks rather cumbersome and inefficient. It requires three vectors and lots of cleanup, reserve and insertion. I wonder if there is any alternative that may be more efficient, or at least as efficient but the code looks much more concise? I've been reading things like stringstream all such but they don't seem to require less memory copy (probably more as my API has to require byte array gets passed in). Thanks!

```
std::vector<char> checkBuffer;
std::vector<char> remainingBuffer;
std::vector<char> readBuffer(READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
//loop while I still have stuff to read from input stream
while (in.good()) {
    in.read(readBuffer.data(), READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    //This is the holding buffer for the API to parse object from
    checkBuffer.clear();
    //concatenate what's remaining in remainingBuffer (initially empty) 
    //with what's newly read from input inside readBuffer
    checkBuffer.reserve(remainingBuffer.size() + readBuffer.size());
    checkBuffer.insert(checkBuffer.end(), remainingBuffer.begin(),
    remainingBuffer.end());
    checkBuffer.insert(checkBuffer.end(), readBuffer.begin(),
    readBuffer.end());
    //Call API here, and I will also get a pointerPosition back as to 
    //where I am inside the buffer when finishing reading the object
    Object parsedObject = parse(checkBuffer, &pointerPosition)
    //Then calculate the size of bytes not read in checkBuffer
    int remainingBufSize = CheckBuffer.size() - pointerPosition;

    remainingBuffer.clear();
    remainingBuffer.reserve(remainingBufSize);
    //Then just copy over whatever is remaining in the checkBuffer into
    //remainingBuffer and make it be used in next iteration
    remainingBuffer.insert(remainingBuffer.end(), 
   &checkBuffer[pointerPosition],&checkBuffer[checkBuffer.size()]);
}
```

Comment: How many items fit in a buffer?  Are they fixed size as well?  Are you reading this data from a file?  Why the fixed buffer size?

Comment: There could be lots of items in one buffer, I tried to simplify that in question by saying one object. The item size varies too, but the API is smart enough to stop when the object parsing is done. I definitely omitted lots of logic around how I detect and achieve that with the API.

Comment: Without some more details it's hard to make a recommendation.  Personally unless there's a good reason not to, I'd just read directly from the file or whatever stream you have.  It's generally incorrect to use `while (in.good())` and not check the return values on the actual read operations.  You may have just read the last byte of the file, it's still good, but the next read will fail and you don't check.

Comment: Working with the fixed size buffer not directly the file is the requirement of the underlying structure. Yes I will certainly be checking the read bytes as well...that's just another detail I omitted for simplification, as it's not relevant to the question I wonder, which is, maybe in general, the most efficient and elegant way to perform these memory copy-ish operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `append_chunk_into(in,vect)`.  It appends one chunk of data at the end of `vect`.  It does resizing as needed.  As an aside, a char-sized does-not-zero-memory standard layout struct might be a better choice than `char`.

To append to end:

```
size_t old_size=vect.size();
vect.resize(vect.size()+new_bytes);
in.read(vect.data()+old_size, new_bytes);
```

or whatever the read api is.

To parse, feed it `vect.data()`.  Get back the pointer of when it ends `ptr`.

Then `vect.erase(vect.begin(), vect.begin()+(ptr-vect.data())) to remove the parsed bytes.  (only do this after you have parsed everything you can from the buffer, to save wasted mem moves).

One vector.  It will reuse its memory, and never grow larger than read size+size of largest object-1.  So you can pre-reserve it.

But really, usually most of the time spent will be io.  So focus optimizarion on keepimg the data flowing smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your position I would keep only the readBuffer. I would reserve `READ_BUFFER_SIZE +sizeof(LargestMessage)`.
After parsing you would be given back a pointer to the last thing the api was able to read in the vector. I would then convert the end iterator to a pointer `&*readbuffer.end()` and use it to bound the data we have to then copy to the head of the vector. once you have that data on the head of the vector you can then read the rest in using that same data call except you add in the number of bytes remaining.  There does need to be some way of determining how many characters were in the remaining array but that shouldn't be insurmountable.